# Ragged list pattern matching, Part 2

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, ragged-list, pattern-matching

*This is a sequel to [Ragged list pattern matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246280/ragged-list-pattern-matching). In this challenge, the wildcard may match a sequence of items of any length instead of just a single item.*

Given a pattern and a ragged list of integers, your task is to decide whether the pattern matches the ragged list.

The pattern is also represented by a ragged list. But in addition to positive integers, it may contain a wildcard value.

Here is the rule for matching:

- A positive integer matches the same positive integer.
- The wildcard value matches a sequence of items (integer or list) of any length, including the empty sequence.
- A ragged list matches a ragged list if each item in the pattern matches the corresponding item in the list.

For example, if we write the wildcard as `0`, then the pattern `[0, [4, [5], 0]]` matches the ragged list `[[1, 2], [3], [4, [5]]]`: here the first `0` matches the sequence `[1, 2], [3]`, and the second `0` matches the empty sequence.

You may choose any fixed value as the wildcard, as long as it is consistent.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

This is [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem). You may use your language's convention for truthy/falsy, or use two distinct, fixed values to represent true or false.

### Testcases

Here I use `0` to represent the wildcard. The input here are given in the order `pattern, ragged list`.

#### Truthy

```
[], []
[0], []
[0], [1, 2]
[0], [[[]]]
[0, 0], [1, 2, 3]
[1, 0], [1, [[2, 3]]]
[1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 0, [2, 3]], [1, [2, 3]]
[1, [2, 0], 4], [1, [2, 3], 4]
[0, [4, [5], 0]], [[1, 2], [3], [4, [5]]]
```

#### Falsy

```
[1], []
[[]], []
[[0]], [3]
[[4]], [4]
[1, 0], [2, 1]
[[0]], [[1], [2]]
[1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 3]
[1, 0, 2, 0], [1, [3, 2, 3]]
[1, [0, 2], 4], [1, [2, 3], 4]
[[0], [4, [5], 0]], [[1, 2], [3], [4, [5]]]
```

Comment: suggest a test case who has two 0’s and expected output is false. When replace 0 by .* in its JSON representation, it matches. For example `[1, 0, 2, 0] [1, [3, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 71 bytes

```
>
,>
<,
<
~(L$`^.+
\n$&$
_,
(\d+,|<((?<_><)|(?<-_>>)|\d|,)+(?(_)^)>,)$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY4xDsIwDEV3nyJDQQk1SKVlIkovwAaba1ykMrAwIDYKVy9Jm1YgMSAlyvf3d/xu5/vlesq6md7XWzjUStPjyaYWa63rHKADi2DhpXdJfVylUF2TeQKCoKsmxdZqXVpx1rT@XYpzpq2aFk2qSy3maByaZNF1xFtFDCSfb4ZqPWoiZq@9NbaI1qjyyQ3ZODOcyY@5ODUUMGphVMVXL9R@qS8LfzccMj1Bj@OtEIm9/qOITDyKIZ8HWfSy@CD3O7JfyHlkkmHLLyYS/pPqDQ) Takes two newline-separated <>-wrapped lists but link is to test suite that deletes spaces, splits on semicolons and converts other types of brackets for convenience. Uses _ to represent the wild card. Explanation: Based on my Retina answer to [Ragged list pattern matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246280/).

```
>
,>
<,
<
```

Ensure that non-empty lists end in a comma.

```
~(
```

Evaluate the result of the transformations below on the comma-safe input. Since they result in a single line, this makes Retina attempt to match the comma-safe input against the result.

```
L$`^.+
\n$&$
```

Take only the first line of the input and wrap it in `\n` and `$` so that it will match against the second line of the input.

```
_,
(\d+,|<((?<_><)|(?<-_>>)|\d|,)+(?(_)^)>,)$*
```

Replace each `_,` with a match against any number (`$*` represents a literal `*` which would otherwise be the string repetition operator) of comma-safe non-negative integers or lists, using a .NET balancing group to ensure that the lists are properly balanced. A named capturing group `?<_>` is used here because .NET allows capturing groups to be reused in this way and it's golfier than calculating the capturing group number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 89 bytes

**Assumption**: ragged lists are defined in the following way:

```haskell
data RL a = L [RL a] | N a | W
  deriving Eq
```

**Solution**:

```haskell
L(W:p)#L x|L p#L x=1>0
L(W:p)#L(_:x)=L(W:p)#L x
L(q:p)#L(y:x)=q#y&&L p#L x
a#b=a==W||a==b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVRdS8MwFH3xKb_iQmU0kIH7EKQYHwQFoexBhCIjjMxms1i7rs1kg_4TX_Yi_ib9NSbNurVbO30QSm_IOefec3ubvH8-8_RFhOH6i_hccrh3gQMFF4Z6xSCDgdrIwEMAvkiCtyCaws38YyEn7YuvR9f2nBhbLiwzF2IdaefqDBXb9shZYrojKWBugJUG5taq1droELfGlFPqZZl6j02B75ORFKlMwXFgaF_PZiEBWxm7iyQBEzFmyHAoDJVJ-yFZCKKiaoER3QjDmOwB3m_IADpEdd5tZpiHsToGgb00-tWrYeZ4mWuybhV12Y3GuDso0m1yXagq2St1d9sN6oKj_Q6g36A2WO1HyWn9TTxnOhPbtdyptNRjB_ytsVsepirtxlh1lCUsH88R0GO7YrUE3cjWRn3x0vTy_jvHS5Ud62YbkzaMt85oSXDwLylFSdskNtMxBf842P32_mW4DCE0UcfYtjBK9HGeQMylFEkECZ9Ohe8GqQRKQSxj8SSFr-4lu1grMxsyKbExhss25PcDQ688iFTaOAkiCafAIx8Sc8-s1yb-AA)